# how can I apply has-error to a single input inside form-group, where multiple inputs exist

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using angularjs and `$invalid` to add `.has-error` to my form group.. problem is one of my form groups has multiple inputs in it, side by side..

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <select class="form-control input-lg" name="location" ng-model="newRack.location" ng-options="location as location.name for location in locations" placeholder="Locations" required></select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="name">Rack Size</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="size" ng-model="newRack.size" min="1" max="48" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

validation would look similar to this, but would include additional validations for the size element as well.

```
 ng-class="{ 'has-error': rackForm.location.$invalid && rackForm.location.$dirty }"
```

if `name=size` becomes invalid, as it stands `.has-error` is applied to the entire form group, and that can be confusing to the end user. Is there a way to either

- apply the .has-error to a specific input
- rearrange my form
  layout a bit so each input is in its own form group, yet still retain
  the side by side look.

Answer (score 1):

The way i do it is to create form-group for each input element. Also, I believe you don't need inner `<div class="col-sm-6">` since you can join that class with form-group and get the same results.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': rackForm.location.$invalid && rackForm.location.$dirty }">
    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <select class="form-control input-lg" name="location" ng-model="newRack.location" ng-options="location as location.name for location in locations" placeholder="Locations" required></select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': rackForm.size.$invalid && rackForm.size.$dirty }">
    <label for="name">Rack Size</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="size" ng-model="newRack.size" min="1" max="48" required>

</div>
```

Let me know if it helped

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you are trying to put too much logic into your HTML. Look in to creating Angular directives that implement your logic behind the scenes or do it in your controller, and set the state you are trying to check on your `scope`.

One of the key precepts of Angular is to not put logic in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without changing your layout, just use `ng-class` sintax in each div with `col` class. Like that:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6"  ng-class="{ 'has-error': rackForm.location.$invalid && rackForm.location.$dirty }">
    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <select class="form-control input-lg" name="location" ng-model="newRack.location" ng-options="location as location.name for location in locations" placeholder="Locations" required></select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"  ng-class="{ 'has-error': rackForm.size.$invalid && rackForm.size.$dirty }">
    <label for="name">Rack Size</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="size" ng-model="newRack.size" min="1" max="48" required>
  </div>
</div>
```